# Native libraries in react-native

Tags: react-native

is there a way to import / include / require native java android or native objective-c / swift in react native apps?

I mean lets say android's libraries like android volley or android libPhoneNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways:

1. If the libraries/modules were already wrapped and exposed be React-Native, then just use it (learn how to do it in the link below).
2. If the libraries/modules were **NOT** wrapped and exposed, then it has to be wrapped and exposed manually first.

Android's Toast library as an example:

- Used as already wrapped and exposed library/module:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toastandroid.html#content
- Used after manual wrapping and exposing: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content

Answer (score 3):

Only if there is react-native Module wrapper for each of those libraries implemented you can use those from the java script side. See more on how to implement Native Modules at 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content